# Propagation in 2d grid using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a 2d grid (made with divs) with attributes "data-x" and "data-y" and I want to do propagation so I made this function:

```
function propagate(tile){
    var x = parseInt(tile.attr('data-x'));
    var y = parseInt(tile.attr('data-y'));

    var adjacent = [
      {x: x-1, y: y-1},
      {x: x, y: y-1},
      {x: x+1, y: y-1},
      {x: x-1, y: y},
      {x: x+1, y: y},
      {x: x-1, y: y+1},
      {x: x, y: y+1},
      {x: x+1, y: y+1}
    ];

    tile.css('background', 'red');

    for(var i = 0; i < adjacent.length; i++){
      var pair = adjacent[i];

      var x = pair.x;
      var y = pair.y;

      var aTile = $('.tile[data-x="'+x+'"][data-y="'+y+'"]');
      propagate(aTile);
  }  
}
```

But I get "Maximum call stack size exceeded" and it propagates in a diagonal line to the top left (makes sense because the first tile that it checks it's the top left one).

I think what's happening is that it checks to the top left, and then the top left of that and so on but when it gets to one that's on the side it doesn't check for the top middle one, it just crashes.

Comment: Tip: `title.data('x')` and `title.data('y')`

Comment: The cause is that after the first step (e.g. calling propagate with `x-1` and `y-1`), it will eventually call `propagate` with the original node again which starts a loop. What's the purpose of your propagate function? Is the positional relationship important? Could you get all tiles at once and then operate on them as a set rather than recursing?

Comment: @ryanjduffy I'm attemping to build a minesweeper from scratch so when you click a tile where there are no numbers (empty tile), it should uncover all adjacent tiles until there's no more to uncover (no more tiles without numbers). What alternative do I have?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest maintaining a list of visited nodes so you don't traverse them twice. I've set up the code below to add that as a parameter to the function but made it optional with `visited = visited || []`. I also added a `revealed` array to track which nodes we successfully visited so you could take action on them.

```js
// a few globals to illustrate
var rows = 5;
var columns = 5;

// easier to maintain the data structure outside of
// the DOM so you can decouple the UI from the data
var board = [
  0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
  1, 1, 0, 0, 1,
  0, 1, 0, 1, 1,
  0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
  1, 0, 0, 0, 1
];

function indexAt (x, y) {
  return y * columns + x;
}

function propagate (x, y, revealed, visited) {
  visited = visited || [];

  var index = indexAt(x, y);

  // check bounds and visited
  if (index < 0 && index >= board.length || visited.indexOf(index) !== -1) {
    return false;
  }

  // in bounds so register it as visited
  visited.push(index);

  // if that position is clear
  if (board[index] === 0) {
    revealed.push(index);

    // check each direction
    propagate(x + 1, y, revealed, visited);
    propagate(x - 1, y, revealed, visited);
    propagate(x, y + 1, revealed, visited);
    propagate(x, y - 1, revealed, visited);
  }

  // if any safe spots were found, return false
  if (revealed.length > 0) {
    return true;
  }

  // otherwise, return false
  return false;
}

function test () {
  var result = document.getElementById('result');
  var revealed, safe;
  
  try {
    revealed = [];
    safe = propagate(0, 0, revealed);

    if (revealed.length !== 2) throw 'Did not find 2';
    if (!safe) throw 'Should have been safe';

    revealed = [];
    safe = propagate(0, 1, revealed);

    if (revealed.length !== 0) throw 'Should not have found any';
    if (safe) throw 'Should have found bomb';
  } catch (msg) {
    result.innerText = 'Test Failed: ' + msg;
    return;
  }

  result.innerText = 'Tests Passed!';
}
```

```html
<button onclick="test()">Start Test</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```